Primevue centralized lazy components loading
I am integrating Primevue in my vue project.
As far as I see in documentation, I need to import components in each vue I use them.
I wonder whether there is a way to have single import statement (either for all components, or for each one I use) in one file, and then use them wherever I need.
I also would like to have a lazy loading (although since all project is compiled to a single .js I don't know if there is a meaning for this).
Is there a way to do it?

This is a bad practice because this prevents you from understanding which components are used and makes the maintenance of the project difficult. And loading all components would load unused components, which is inefficient. Component imports are handled with IDE autoimport feature and aren't generally a problem. Any way, what you ask about is possible and already covered in the docs https://primevue.org/autoimport/ . You may still have problems with this, like the comps that aren't imported may not be recognized by IDE
